# Distinguishable Objects and Distinguishable Boxes with Extra Objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

If there are 40 blue balls, 20 red balls, and 30 green balls, and pick 9 balls. How do I get the probability of getting exactly 3 blue balls and 4 red balls?

I believe the way to go about this is to think about this by breaking it into the numerator and denominator. The denominator seems a bit straight forward in terms of C(90,9).

For the numerator my initial thought was (40/90)*(39/89)*(38/88)+(20/87)…(28/82).

Where am I going wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be *adding* terms in the numerator, but *multiplying* them.

Without loss of generality we can assign numbers to the balls to make them distinct. The total number of selections is then $\binom{90}9$, out of which $\binom{40}3\binom{20}4\binom{30}2$ are of the desired type – the last term coming from the fact that we need 3 green balls to complete the selection of 9. The final probability is
$$\frac{\binom{40}3\binom{20}4\binom{30}2}{\binom{90}9}$$